# Given that imaginary numbers exist perpendicular to a number line, intersecting at 0, does i = 0/0?

Tags: complex-numbers

If imaginary numbers bisect real numbers at zero, am I correct in thinking $0i = 0$?

And if so, does that mean $i = 0/0$?

**EDIT:**

I’ve just realised my careless error in my thought process.

I immediately just “removed” the $0$ from both sides without thinking about the fact that I was actually simplifying $\frac{0i}{0}=\frac{0}{0}$ to $i=\frac{0}{0}$ despite $\frac{0}{0}\neq1$, meaning $\frac{0}{0}i \neq i$

Comment: Why use the imaginary numbers here?  You already have $0\times 1=0$ so does that mean that $1=\frac 00$?

Comment: $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined. We are not allow to divide by $0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting way of looking at this question is to ask the following (to expand on Lulu's answer:
If we have $0\cdot 1 = 0$, why is $1\neq \frac{0}{0}$?
The answer is, of course, that $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, and the zero element has no inverse. Therefore, from a pure algebraic perspective, $\frac00$ makes no sense.

Now we can ask ourselves the same question in $\mathbb{C}$.
Is $\mathbb{C}$ a field? What does that imply for your question?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but as I commented on Parcly's answer, "According to wikipedia i^2 = -1, does that mean i = sqrt(-1)? Which as far as i know isnt possible?"

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible? May I ask what mathematical background you have?

Comment: Just started A level pure maths 1 recently.

Comment: Ok. In that case, just think of $i$ as an abstract symbol defined exactly so serve the purpose of solving the equation $i^2=-1$. That is, we're expanding the numbers so that it is allowed.

Comment: As you will later see, if you pursue mathematics further, this definition of $i$ has a more formal technique behind it. Namely that $\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)$.
We say that the complex numbers are isomorphic to the latter construction.

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation That's a bad idea, since we then get to the question of $1 = \sqrt{1} = \sqrt{-1\cdot-1}=\sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{-1} = i\cdot i = -1$. It's better to think of $i$ as the symbol whose purpose is that $i^2=-1$.

Comment: @5xum You are very right, sir. I will correct my comment.

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation Thank you for explaining it fully! (at least as much as I can understand)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $0i=0$, but the prohibition on dividing by zero remains valid in the complex plane, and one does not conclude $i=0/0$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I however have a followup question, According to wikipedia `i^2 = -1`, does that mean `i = sqrt(-1)`? Which as far as i know isnt possible?

Comment: @SgtOddball Then ask another question!

Comment: Sorry, havent used stack exchange in a while and forgot you couldnt add lines with enter on a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's also true that $0\cdot 1 = 0$. Does that mean $1=\frac00$?

It's also true that $0\cdot 2 = 0$. Does that mean $2=\frac00$?

Comment: That isn't an answer, but I see what you're doing.

Comment: @SgtOddball It may not be the answer you wanted, but it should be the one you need.

Comment: Those are 2 questions.

Comment: @SgtOddball Indeed they are. And how would you answer them?